# How to login to the website and use the login connection to parse another pages

Tags: java, jsoup

I am trying the following:

```
Connection.Response res = Jsoup.connect("http://www.nordicnet.se/Login.aspx?height=408&width=490&mode=1").userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/535.21 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1042.0 Safari/535.21").data("tbUserName", "username", "tbPassword", "password").method(Method.POST).execute();
System.out.println(res.toString());
String sessionId = res.cookie("cook");
System.out.println("Session Id"+sessionId);
Document doc;
doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.nordicnet.se/foretag/Viafin-Process-Piping-AB/1248169/").cookie("cook", sessionId).timeout(10*1000).get();
```

However, I am unable to create a login session and use the same connection to parse another page.

Comment: What is your result of `System.out.println(res.cookies());`?

Comment: nothing i get . Its null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hard to be sure without real user pass, but I do see that there are other parameters in the form on the page, these are the post parameters copied from firebug:

```
__EVENTVALIDATION=/wEWAwKN6cKWAwLyj/OQAgKXtYSMCscHt6cC4FDeXTt5x3mYsdjD8St4
__VIEWSTATE=/wEPDwULLTE4ODE4ODcyMjBkZOuwb1/ExHPAeKuIx34zh6mjfI29
tbPassWord=pass
tbUserName=user
```

you'll have to first get the page, then parse for `__EVENTVALIDATION` and `__VIEWSTATE` to find their generated values and only then add them to the POST data.

EDIT: also note a small typo, change "tbPassword" to "tbPassWord"

Comment: please ping me at my gmail rishikesh.rv  I am unable to send my code .

Comment: It was perfect answer . You are the greatest expert .